# Reading int data from file using istream

Tags: c++, stl, stream

```
ifstream dataFile("ints.dat");

istream_iterator<int> dataBegin(dataFile);
istream_iterator<int> dataEnd;

list<int> data(dataBegin, dataEnd);
```

I have above code in C++ STL.

Above code is working.

we are creating begin and end iterator as data begin and data end. But dataEnd is not related to data file. How list knows the range?

Comment: Think of `dataEnd` as a glorified EOF constant,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's usual to see that as `std::istream_iterator<int> eos;`, as in the [ref](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/istream_iterator/)'s example, for instance, but in your case the name chosen by you might be a better fit.

It's an analogy to `EOF`, which for standard input, end-of-file represents 1 past the last element to be read.

`eos` is something like a last iterator that represents 1 past the last element to be read.

It's similar to `EOF`, but as you see not the same. For example, what you name your end of stream really doesn't matter. In the link I provided above, there is a possible implementation, which you can study, if you like.

Moreover, [cpprefernce](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) mentions:

> The default-constructed std::istream_iterator is known as the
>   *end-of-stream* iterator. When a valid std::istream_iterator reaches the
>   end of the underlying stream, it *becomes equal to the end-of-stream
>   iterator*. Dereferencing or incrementing it further invokes undefined
>   behavior.

And from [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/istream_iterator/operators/), we have this:

> These operators are overloaded in header [`<iterator>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/).

Comment: What you name your end of stream really doesn't matter. In the context of OP's example, I prefer the name `dataEnd` to `eos`, because it more obviously relates to what it is marking